# Software to allow people to read my PDF but not print nor copy it (free alternative to Artistscope Copysafe PDF Protector)

Tags: gratis, pdf, drm

I need software to encrypt my PDF file so it can not be printed and copied.

I already found software that can do this, such as Copysafe PDF Protector from Artistscope. But the problem is I can not fint an alternative to it that I can use freely without buying a license (budget problem).

Is there any alternative free software that can do this like Copysafe PDF protector?

Comment: If you can open a PDF, you can print it. Everything else is just DRM which just can be ignored by any tool and leads to issues for the user on the other hand. Please consider thinking whether DRM is really what you are looking for.

Comment: This is different story, Copysafe has its own PDF viewer, therefor people can not make excuse to any copyright issues.

This is the workflow:

1. Open Copysafe Protector
2. Select PDF file: secret_doc.pdf
3. Set permission (no print, no copy, add password)
4. Save & Close

As the result Copysafe will output the encripted PDF file secret_doc.pdf.enc

To open the file we need the viewer

1. Open Copysafe PDF Reader
2. Select file: secret_doc.pdf.enc
3. File opened in the viewer that have very nice UI. Complete PDF viewer with heading pointer, search etc
4. User can not print or copy the document

Comment: I'm searching a software that can do this things.

Comment: For me you are not talking about pdf anymore but about some proprietary  container format.

Comment: Yes... other encrypted container format that can hold a pdf. Container + viewer

Comment: did you find an alternative???

Answer (score 1):

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) provides the encryption options and is free *or paid at a tiny amount under $4 for the pro version.*

Example of encryption:

> Encrypt a PDF using 128-bit strength (the default), withhold all
>   permissions (the default)

```
pdftk 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf owner_pw foopass
```

Comment: no pdftk is not the options, see my comment above about the software i mean.. the encryptor and the viewer... thanks